# Understanding the functionallity of onCreateViewHolder()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewholder

So I implemented this method based on a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/HtwDXRWjMcU?t=859) :

```
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TestAdapterHodl {
        
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent,false)
        return TestAdapterHodl(view)
    }
```

As far as I know, onCreateViewHolder() is called when the recycler needs a new viewHolder.
The line:

```
val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent,false)
```

inflates the `item_card.xml` file for the viewHolder.

But I dont understand what `.from(parent.context)` does and what `parent` is.
I would love to know it so I can understand it completely.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LayoutInfalter` is the class that is responsible for instantiating `XML` views into their corresponding objects. It creates all the views. We never use it directly, instead, we get the already attached inflater to the `context` and use it to inflate layouts.

> But I dont understand what `.from(parent.context)`

`from(context)` is a method of the `LayoutInflater` class that returns the `inflater` instance currently attached to the given context.

> what `parent` is

`parent` is the `RecyclerView` to which you are setting this adapter.